# Restart a pushbutton counter

Tags: if-statement, arduino, counter, arduino-uno, lcd

I have to do two counters with Arduino and show it on an LCD. But counters have to restart when they reach 99.

I've done this:

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int boton_user = 0;
int boton_admin = 1;

int user_actual = 0;
int user_antes = 1;
int admin_actual = 0;
int admin_antes = 1;

int num_actual = 0;
int num_ultimo = 0;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(boton_user, INPUT);
  pinMode(boton_admin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  user_actual = digitalRead(boton_user);

  if(user_actual != user_antes) {
    if(user_actual == HIGH) {

      if(num_ultimo == 99) {
        num_ultimo = 1;
      }else{
        num_ultimo = num_ultimo + 1;
      }
    }
    user_antes = user_actual;
  }

  admin_actual = digitalRead(boton_admin);

  if(admin_actual != admin_antes) {
    if(admin_actual == HIGH && num_actual < num_ultimo) {

      if(num_actual == 99) {
        num_actual = 1;
      }else{
        num_actual = num_actual + 1;
      }
    }
    admin_antes = admin_actual;
  }

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Siguiente: ");
  lcd.print(num_actual);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Ultimo: ");
  lcd.print(num_ultimo);
}
```

But when any number reaches 99, it will only change the first 9 (97, 98, 99, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 99...) and the second time it reaches 99 it will change to 10 and start again (...10, 11, 12...97, 98, 99, 19, 29...).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite `Siguiente: 99` with `Siguiente: 1` and you get `Siguiente: 19`, because the last character is kept.

Call `lcd.clear()`, before you update the LCD.